# MDX query to use a set but return a single row

Tags: mdx

I am new to MDX and have just started using Named sets to group several members of a dimension.
Whenever I use a SET in a query, the results returned are always detailed out for each individual member of the set. I am looking to get one one for the set.

For example:  I have two Measures:  Sales Dollars and Shipped Units.  The then have a State dimension for each of the 50 states in the United States.

I want to see the Sales and Units measures for 3 specific states and then also for a group (Named Set) of 4 other states.

Example MDX:

```
With SET [My Favorite States] AS '{[States].[Illinois], [States].[Wisconsin]}'
select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Sales], [Measures].[Shipped Units]} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY {[States].[Alabama], [States].[New York], [My Favorite States]} ON ROWS
from [cubename]
```

This returns:

```
           Measures
States     Sales       Shipped Units
Alabama     $100              5
New York    $500             20
Illinois    $150             15
Wisconsin   $900             25
```

What I want is for the Set to appear as a total on a single line.   Similar to:

```
                     Measures
States               Sales       Shipped Units
Alabama               $100              5
New York              $500             20
My Favorite States    $1,050           40
```

Is there an MDX function that will allow the set of specific members to be treated as a group?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a calculated member to aggregate the separate states:

```
With Member [States].[My Favorite States] AS 'Aggregate({[States].[Illinois], [States].[Wisconsin]})' 
select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Sales], [Measures].[Shipped Units]} ON COLUMNS, 
  NON EMPTY {[States].[Alabama], [States].[New York], [States].[My Favorite States]} ON ROWS 
from [cubename]
```